# Issue with HOUR_OF_DAY of Calendar

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat

In Debug mode I see that the value I'm parsing is equal to `"2015-09-01 22:00"`. When I create a Calendar I see that `HOUR_OF_DAY` is equal to 22.
However, `interval` is equal to 10 instead of 22. Where is an error?

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         try {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse("2015-09-01 22:00"));
        int interval = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY-1);
        System.out.println(interval);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please ask *one* question per post... ideally with a short but *complete* example.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, by the way. It returns 22 for me. If you could provide a short but complete program which *does* demonstrate the problem on your machine, that would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Here you have it http://goo.gl/7SZt2D
Just execute the code to see the result (10).

Comment: a) The code should be in the *question*, not in a link. b) that code uses `c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY - 1)` which is almost certainly the problem. If you'd put that code *in the question* to start with, this all could have been sorted out in seconds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not asking for the `HOUR_OF_DAY` value - you're asking for the `HOUR_OF_DAY - 1` value, which actually corresponds to `Calendar.HOUR` - the 12-hour version:

> Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the morning or afternoon. HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock (0 - 11). Noon and midnight are represented by 0, not by 12. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR is 10.

Just change your code to

```
int interval = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

... and it will be fine.

Comment: Ok. I should do int interval = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) - 1 to follow my logic. Thanks.

Comment: @Klausos: Well we don't know why you want to subtract an hour to start with... Consider what you want to happen if the hour is already 0...